# Getting output of system commands that use pipes (Python)

Tags: python, linux, pipe

I'm trying to generate a random string using this command:

`strings /dev/urandom | grep -o '[[:alnum:]]' | head -n 30 | tr -d '\n';`

Works fine, but when I try to do `subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)` it just gets stuck on the strings /dev/urandom command and spams my screen with `grep: writing output: Broken pipe`

What's causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: what if you add `executable = '/bin/bash'` explicitly to the `call`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for subprocess, observe:

```
>>> import base64
>>> r = open("/dev/urandom","r")
>>> base64.encodestring(r.read(22))[:30]
'3Ttlx6TT3siM8h+zKm+Q6lH1k+dTcg'
>>> r.close()
```

Also, `strings`ing and then `grep`ing alphanumeric characters from `/dev/urandom` is *hugely* inefficient and wastes a whole lot of randomness. On my desktop PC, the above python takes less than 10 ms to executed from bash, your `strings ...` oneliner takes 300-400...

For a pure python solution that works also on systems without `/dev/urandom` - and gives only alphanumeric characters (if you really don't want + or /):

```
import string
import random
''.join([random.choice(string.printable[:62]) for i in range(30)])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for what you're doing, it should be better to generate the string using python directly.

Anyway, when using `subprocess`, the correct way to pipe data from a process to another is by redirecting `stdout` and/or `stderr` to a `subprocess.PIPE`, and feed the new process' `stdin` with the previous process' `stdout`.